# How to start AsyncTask during another AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Subject code is:

```
public class AsyncTask1 extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Boolean>{
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params){
        //...
        asyncTask2 = new AsyncTask2();
        //...
        Log.i("AsyncTask1","Launch asyncTask2");
        String taskResult = tasyncTask2.execute().get().toString();
        //...
    }
    //...
}

public class AsyncTask2 extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, String>{
//...
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params){
    Log.i("AsyncTask2", "I have started");
    //...
}
//...
}
```

This code template works on 2.3.5 and 4.2, but after Jelly Bean update it's not working. Why?

2.3.5

AsyncTask1 notification +

AsyncTask2 notification +

4.2 (after update):

AsyncTask1 notification +

AsyncTask2 notification -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation part of Asynctask task after Jellybean , The Asynctask instance must be created on the UI thread.and u r creating instance n executing its operation in doing background of another asycntask which is another worker thread not UI thread.So you should not create/execute instance of asynctask in other than UI thread

Answer (score 0):

By default AsyncTask.execute is single threaded on Android 3.0+ per [the documentation on execute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#execute%28Params...%29).

Per [this blog](http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/04/20/asynctask-threading-regression-confirmed.html), you can replace your tasyncTask2.execute().get().toString() with:

```
String taskResult;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    taskResult = tasyncTask2.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR).get().toString();
}
else {
    taskResult = tasyncTask2.execute().get().toString();
}
```

Or combine your AsyncTasks by replacing your tasyncTask2.execute().get().toString() a local method call to what you do in the doInBackground method of AsyncTask2.

Comment: THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR added since API Level 11

Comment: @Sunshine - yes, Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB === 11

Comment: What about GINGERBREAD_MR1? Can you advice somethin`?

Comment: @Sunshine You can have a copy of `AsyncTask` getting from Android source Level 11, I do it all the time.